# Let $P$ denote a subset of a linear space $L$, why does the set $P$ always contains a basis of $span\,P$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ denote a subset of a linear space $L$, why does the set $P$ always contains a basis of $span\,P$.

In my opinion it is not the case. For example if $P$ consists of two vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$, the basis can be $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ which does not belong to $P$.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: The distinction is between sub*set* and sub*space* I think. Subsets don't play nicely with the vector space axioms. That is what subspaces are for.

Comment: The two vectors $(1,0), (1,1)$ **are** a basis for $\operatorname{sp} P$. Is $L$ finite dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counterexample is not really a counterexample...  Although it is true that $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is indeed a basis of $\mbox{span}P$, the set $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ is *also* a basis, and each of these vectors is an element of $P$.  Your theorem does not say that $P$ contains *all possible choices* of basis for $\mbox{span}P$, only that it must contain *at least one*.

Denote $U=\mbox{span}P$.  To see why $P=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ is a basis for $U$, first notice that this $P$ is linearly independent.  If $a(1,0)+b(1,1)=0$, then $(a+b,b)=0$, which implies $b=0$, and, consequently, $a=0$, showing that $P$ is linearly independent.  Then, we know that $P$ is a spanning set for $U=\mbox{span}P$ by definition of span.  Therefore, $P$ is linearly independent and spans $U$, so is a basis for $U$.

Comment: ah, I got it. Surely it always contain the basis of span of P, but it does not mean it can not contain other things.